# "Attach Process" for Silverlight solution not working

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight

I have a silverlight solution file.For some reason i can not Do run on solution by clicking on green triangle.so i use a hosted application and attach that silverlight instance to the solution file but no break point is hit.

Note : i have 2 instance on running hosted silverlight app.

1. iexploere for internet explorer of Silverlight app
2. Silverlight App

I attach to both of them.

Please comment if you dont understand the question rather than de-vote

Answer (score 0):

Some things to check:

1. Make sure the web project hosting your Silverlight app is the startup project.
2. Make sure the web page hosting your Silverlight app is the start page.
3. Make sure the web project hosting your Silverlight app has Silverlight debugging enabled (right click, properties, web tab, debuggers).
4. Make sure you have the developer version of the Silverlight client installed.